# Mapping Dictionary of Functions to DataFrame based on Key

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

**Description**

I currently have a dictionary of functions, which all perform different string operations, given an input string as a parameter *(see Figure 1. below)*. I also have an existing pandas DataFrame with one or more of the same dictionary keys below, in addition to a name and type of name *(see Figure 2. below):*

**Required**

I'm looking to map the functions stored in the dictionary under Figure 1. to the DataFrame names (column SDN_NAME), based on the key stored in the dictionary and column S-ID in the DataFrame.

- **Note**: Each function stored in the dictionary may perform different operations, which will result in different output for each input string.

Please provide any assistance / recommendations in executing the following process above.

**Figure 1:**

```
scenarios = {
    '1-A': function1(), 
    '1-B': function2(), 
    '1-C': function3(), 
    '1-D': function4()
}
```

**Figure 2:**

[image: See DataFrame]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Do you know about pandas `.apply()` method? Also, please don't post images of data, but textual representation of your data - so that we can work with your data in our code when we check our solutions.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

def f(x):
    return len(x)
def g(x):
    return len(x)/2

d = {'a':f,'b':g}

t = pd.DataFrame({'key':['a','a','b','a'],'v':['harsha','har','asdf','h']})

t['output'] = t.apply(lambda x: d[x['key']](x['v']),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  key       v  output
0   a  harsha     6.0
1   a     har     3.0
2   b    asdf     2.0
3   a       h     1.0
```

Comment: Thanks Assetti, this worked. I was attempting to use applymap, but works fine!